# Getting build error with ANgular 6 and Billboard.js chart library

Tags: javascript, angular, billboard.js

I am trying to use billboard.js chart library with Angular 6 and it working fine for development purpose. When I run `ng build --prod` i am geting following error

```
chunk {0} common.dc8a8d222642a54a5dd0.js (common) 7.59 kB [rendered]
... 
chunk {42} main.1bcccf62608b1d9f24f9.js (main) 1.46 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/billboard.js/dist/billboard.js
Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
at getJSDocTags (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:13197:22)
at getFirstJSDocTag (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:13205:24)
at Object.getJSDocTypeTag (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:13154:19)
at checkParenthesizedExpression (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45628:56)
at checkExpressionWorker (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45676:28)
at checkExpression (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45609:42)
at checkBinaryLikeExpression (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45155:29)
at checkBinaryExpression (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45147:20)
at checkExpressionWorker (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45702:28)
at checkExpression (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45609:42)
at checkExpressionCached (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45457:38)
at getTypeOfExpression (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45577:28)
at checkDeclarationInitializer (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45469:24)
at getTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30738:28)
at getWidenedTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30961:24)
at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (/Users/.../backend-new/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31062:28)
```

Note :The build works smoothly in Angular 8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the same problem https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24577

Comment: @Hsuan Lee this is not helpful. Tried the methods mentioned there. But still no use. This issue is not occurring in Angular 7 too.